# Emacs AUCTeX & TL 2018 - Problems with non ASCII characters in the file name

Tags: compiling, emacs, auctex, texlive-2018

My recent update to TeX Live 2018 has led to a curious problem. I can no longer compile files whose names have non ASCII characters with Emacs + AUCTeX.

That is curious because nothing on the side of Emacs has changed. I'm using Emacs from the OS's repositories (namely Linux Mint 18.3 and Emacs version 24.5.1) and AUCTeX is installed through ELPA (that is with `M-x package-install` from within Emacs, namely version 12.1.1).

But, what works fine with TeX Live 2017, no longer works with TeX Live 2018.

Take a file named **primárias.tex** with contents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello World!!
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

(The content is not relevant, the file name is).

This produces me the error:

> ERROR: I can't find file `prim'.

Everything works fine with TeXworks, TeXstudio or with compilation through the command line.

Any ideas of what might be going wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: I'm just looking for the auctex variable but you want to do `latex \\input \\detokenize{primárias.tex} ` not `latex \\input primárias.tex `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for your comment. But, as far as I know, I'm using defaults for compilation. So I'm counting on Emacs to do its magic. Which means I'm not instructing it to `latex \\input primárias.tex` (at least not explicitly).

Comment: auctex uses that form (rather than `latex  primárias.tex` and (today at least) that doesn't work with the 2018-04-01 release as the new default UTF-8 code confuses it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is this a temporary problem, or means a permanent change? In the later case, should this be reported to AUCTeX? And, in either case, how could I instruct AUCTeX do get things right in the meantime?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, please let me know when you do. And thank you so far!

Comment: I hope you accepted jfbu's version rather than my initial one (which worked but was not as nice:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We (for some definition of "we") will sort something out, but for now you can customize the latex command as follows (thanks jfbu)

customize `TeX-command-list` to contain

```
("LaTeX" "%`%l%(mode)%' \\\\detokenize{%t}" TeX-run-TeX nil 
                       (latex-mode doctex-mode) :help "Run LaTeX")
```

Recipe for customizing the variable: `C-h v TeX-command-list` then click on customize then in customization buffer find the `LaTeX` entry and replace there `%t` by `\\detokenize{%t}` then either `Apply` or `Apply and Save` for it to become permanent across sessions.

Comment: it would be better to add `\detokenize{...}` rather than `\UseRawInputEncoding` but it seems my emacs lisp is getting rusty and that defeated me

Comment: or perhaps intervene at level of `("%t" file t t)` in TeX-expand-list-builtin but that's more for teh AUCTeX folks to do.

Comment: @jfbu that's what I thought I tried first but i messed up somewhere, if there is a version along those lines that works,  could you post an answer or edit this one, i don't really want to tell people to edit the variable as above.

Comment: For the record, David Kastrup has good reasons to use `\input` to compile the document, but I don't remember exactly them (I think it has to do with some magics to make region compilation work)

Comment: @giordano I have pinged David to warn him of this

Comment: @jfbu thanks, I stole your text and re-wrote the answer.

Comment: DavidCarlile and @jfbu, thank you very much!

Comment: DavidCarlile, do I understand correctly (the edited answer) and uft8 became default for pdflatex, so that I no longer need `[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Comment: @gusbrs yes see latex news 28 that ships with the latex release

Comment: DavidCarlile, that's very good news. I just signed the feed of the project, not to miss other such treats.  :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For the record, this issue is gone in recent versions of AUCTeX (precisely by employing `\detokenize` internally, if needed). The ChangeLog entry for 2018-05-28 is "Accept non-ascii file name in accord with change in TL 2018".